# tqft or topological-quantum-field-theory? Which one to keep?

Tags: discussion, tagging, tag-management

A fairly new member of our MSE community, namely the user [*Andrews*](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/557551/andrews), started to reshape our own physical questions fundamentally basically by retagging them in an appropriate manner. Another recently posted [Meta question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29913/some-ideas-on-tags-about-physical-field-theory) of his own deals in more detail with his aim. I appreciate his effort and it is good to see that there are in fact people who bother to accomplish such a comprehensive task.

However, today I reviewed a [Suggested Edit](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/1165967) from the aforementioned user adding the newly created tag [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory). As he pointed out by himself within the linked Meta Question the currently existing tag [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) is not adequate, especially the current name. To be precise he wrote

> ...although tqft is an abbreviation, it's hard for users to find the existence of this tag or recall this when adding tags.[*...*] I sincerely suggest rename this tag as [topological-field-theory] for users' convenience, and this doesn't change its meaning. What's more, the tag info should be updated.

Now we are left with the situation of two identical tags which are **not** listed as synonyms. For the sake of clarity I would suggest to keep the newly created [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) and to mark the old [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) as synonym following the argumentation from above as it is more clear what the first one refers to.

> What are your thoughts concerning this issue? Hence I have not got a score of $5$ or more on the tag [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) nor on [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) I cannot suggest this synonym directly by myself.

Comment: There is also a request on the tags management 2019 thread, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29718/tag-management-2019/29916#29916

Comment: This seems like an uncontroversial step.  At some point the length allowed for tag names was increased, from [25 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/192763/a-better-alternative-to-unauthorizedaccessexcepti-tag) to [35 characters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).  Even so, "topological-quantum-field-theory" is a mouth full.

Comment: @hardmath: And there are arguments to "topological-quantum-field-theories" being the right tag name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have already change [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) to [topological-quantum-field-theory](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/topological-quantum-field-theory) in questions, there're no questions with [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) [now](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft).

Since there're few users suggest a synonym and vote for it, maybe we can delete [tqft](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tqft) now?

Comment: There is again as somebody rolled back your edit. Tags exist by virtue of being on questions, there is no need or even way to delete them specifically. It is always possible for moderators to create synonyms and to do renames in bulk. That it was not yet done is also due to the fact that there was  no consensus yet.  Since it was only a few questions its not a big deal, but generally it's better to wait a bit more. That said, thanks for your efforts to improve tagging.

Comment: I will add that the tags related to TQFT and the recent activity around them were also [mentioned in the tagging chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/3740?m=49390875#49390875). From your recent posts on meta it seems that you're interested in tags - so knowing that such room exists might be useful for you. (Although I have to admit that the activity in that room is not very high.)